# Telepaths working as spies that die young

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy

I read a thriller/sci-fi novel about 15 years ago involving a government program using telepaths as spies. This is during the Cold War, so the Russians have a competing program. The down side is the telepaths die very young from their powers.

I recall they called the telepaths "Aces."

I seem to remember the hero running off with his girlfriend and making a living by winning (very easily) at poker.  Oddly, I also recall a circus being involved in the big finale.

The big reveal is :

> The government actually fakes the disease and kills the telepaths young to prevent them running off or gathering too many secrets.

Two clarifications: This is not the film "Speed of Thought" from a couple of years ago, in fact that movie is the reason I ask the question. The plot is identical, but the movie does not reference the book I read at all. Also, it is not from the "Wildcards" series of super-hero books, even though they both use the "Aces" label for powered people.

Thoughts?

Comment: I know this one, I just can't think of the title or author. The girlfriend is a russian telepath, and they die young from, er, *something* syndrome? At least that's what they've always been *told...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is it - [*The Sensitives,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/042511581X) by Herbert Berkholz. First published in 1987.

from the Amazon editorial review:

> The "sensitives" are bright adolescents and young adults with a useful
>   but limited ability to read people's thoughts and communicate
>   wordlessly with each other. As soon as they are found, they're brought
>   to a special center in Washington, run by kindly Pop Mickelson, and
>   trained for intelligence work. But the condition that blesses them is
>   also their curse: Rauschner's Syndrome results in death by the age of
>   32. One of the sensitives, ace agent Ben Slade, has a pivotal role, in a race between the superpowers for a new computer component.
>   Interpolated in the account of his disillusionment with the dirty
>   tricks of the intelligence business are the international adventures
>   of his chums, who stick together like a cliquey group of honors
>   students.

Here's a passage from chapter 2:

> ...We had a fair idea, by then, of what we were.
>   We knew that we were psychic freaks with a talent beyond explanation.
>   **We knew that we were the aces;** the deuces had been weeded out by then.
>   We knew that we were something special. What we did not know was the
>   price we would have to pay for that special
>   talent.
>      It was Pop's job to tell us that
>   part of it, explaining Rauschner's Syndrome. It was a sad job, and a
>   delicate one. He had to tell us that Rauschner's was a neurological
>   disorder that we had been born with, that there was no cure for it,
>   and that the survival rate was zero. That the blessing which had given
>   us our rare abilities eventually would kill us.